# Do I have to update Windows 7 if all I use it for is Steam?

Tags: windows, security, updates

I am mostly an Ubuntu user, I have a Windows 7 Home partition for nothing except:

1. Steam and GOG games
2. Updating the BIOS (if I have to and cannot do so from Ubuntu)

Presumably I do not need to keep an antivirus running. But should I still update Windows? If the answer is 'no', then I further ask if there is a way to lock down all of the Internet ports so that absolutely no connections to Microsoft (for updates, telemetry, etc.) or anybody else can be made, except the whitelisted ones for Steam and GOG games?

Thank you

Comment: You should do all the updates and use an antivirus such as norton antivirus that is cheap and fast. What kind of games are you playing?

Comment: Mostly multiplayer Steam games like Brutal Legend. However I would like clarification about your response. In what ways is Windows vulnerable if I lock it down completely except for Steam and certain GOG games? The only thing I can think of is if VALVe servers are compromised, but I'm willing to risk that. I wouldn't be vulnerable to botnets or trojans, right?

Comment: Yeah you wouldn't be vulnerable to botnets and trojans for sure, but I personally don't suggest doing that. Instead, I will at least install critical updates and an antivirus. Or just do the critical updates and disconnect your PC from Internet, except Steam and GOG. Or, you should use PeerBlock. Basically it's a simple firewall. It does simple IP & port blocks, rather than blocking the entire app. You can block Microsoft from there. But using PeerBlock on it's own isn't going to secure your PC like that. You should get a firewall and use peerblock, but update your PC on a monthly basis

Comment: For what reason do you suggest updating my PC?

Comment: Because there are plenty of security holes and zero-day exploits that can ruin everything etc.. When you update your PC regularly, it no longer has these security holes, meanwhile that you're safe more then ever

Comment: But if I locked down everything except Steam (into "kiosk mode" or whatever it is called) and close all other Internet ports, wouldn't the security hole have to go through Steam in order to affect me? In which case, I am dependent upon Steam being secure anyway?

Comment: Yeah but think about a security hole in kiosk mode? You better update mate :)

Comment: Updates aren’t just for security, they also fix bugs that could software to crash or malfunction. Games may also depend on libraries that, in turn, depend on Windows updates.

Comment: I never update my Wii U or Playstation consoles because all I do is play games on them .. but if Nintendo or Sony said their consoles can be used as a drive-by to gain further access to a network and a fix was available, I'm either updating them or ripping out the network hardware all together .. anecdotally what you essentially have is a Windows based [Steam Machine](http://store.steampowered.com/hardware/) .. would you make sure your Steam Machine was up-to-date when feasible?

Comment: I'm a big believer of it's not broke, don't fix it. Some times things go wrong with updates and somethings terribly wrong! I usually only update my PC when I feel I need to and I accept the security risks. I don't do anything daft with my PC any way, no dodgy downloads/websites and as such, I've not had issues! Keeping the AV and Internet security up to date is (IMO) more important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a blunt answer, no, you do not have to... you do not have to do anything as long as the applications work, but that isn't always the best course of action. You SHOULD apply any security or critical updates at least, these are intended to fix security issues or exploits that are known. Regardless of how you lock down your system via Kiosk mode or close ports in the firewall these pose a potential risk. That is why these things are called exploits or security holes, they could, potentially, give an attacker an exploit into your machine that is not a normal way of access that is closed off through your mentioned methods.